# Custom date query while fetching in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Link of the API-[Link](http://fathomless-shelf-5846.herokuapp.com/api/schedule?date=%227/8/2019%22)

The link I have provided ends with a date in format dd/mm/yyyy. It looks like this (http://fathomless-shelf-5846.herokuapp.com/api/schedule?date=%227/8/2019%22). You can replace the date at the end to get results of a different date. If you want to try it, there are some dates where it returns a blank json. So try it for a variety of dates.

I am using reactJS. Now, my problem is that I want to take a custom input date from the user and then insert it in the link above, and then fetch the data of that date. But I have very little knowledge of fetch queries. So please provide some suggestions on how to do it.

I am pasting my App.js code below. Don't get confused by that proxy URL. I am using it for CORS issue.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import Header from './components/Header';

const App=()=> {
  const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
  const targetUrl = 'http://fathomless-shelf-5846.herokuapp.com/api/schedule?date=%227/8/2019%22';

  const [allData,setData]=useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
  },[]);

  const getData =  async () =>{
    const response= await fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl);
    const data=await response.json();
    setData(data);
    console.log(data);
  }

  return( 
    <div className="App">
      <Calendar />
      {allData.map(dta=>(
        <Header head={dta.description} st={dta.start_time} et={dta.end_time}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need insert an input like

`<input type="date" onChange={v => callBackEnd(v.target.value)}/>`

and make your function to call

```
 const callBackEnd = async (v) =>{

let result = await fetch(targetUrl+ new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric'
}).format(v)
const data=await response.json();

 setData(data);

}
```

and you need remove from targetUrl the date to works

Comment: But how can I pass the input date in the URL. I need to put the input date in the URL to fetch data from API.

Comment: when you call the function "callBackEnd" you will get the data from input and in will make fetch will send to your api and for last will call setData to set in your state allData

Comment: It worked man. I did some syntax changes also and it worked. Thank you!